# I'm stuck on a C++ program that i'm writing for my computer science class

Tags: c++, c++14

When I try to run this program it outputs 0 for my `getTotalCost()` function and I cannot figure out why.

Here are Two classes files:

***ShoppingCart.cpp***

```
#include "ShoppingCart.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

ShoppingCart::ShoppingCart()
{
    customerName = "None";
}

ShoppingCart::ShoppingCart(string name)
{
     customerName = name;
}

string ShoppingCart::getCustomerName() const
{
    return customerName;
}

void ShoppingCart::addItem(ItemToPurchase item)
{
    cartItems.push_back(item);
}

void ShoppingCart::removeItem(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size(); i++)
    {
        if (cartItems.at(i).getName() == name)
        {
            cartItems.erase(cartItems.begin() + i);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Item not found in cart. Nothing removed." << endl;
        }
    }

}

void ShoppingCart::changeQuantity(string name, int quantity)
{
    for (int i = 0;  i < cartItems.size(); i++)
    {
        if (cartItems.at(i).getName() == name)
        {
            cartItems[i].setQuantity(quantity);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Item not found in cart. Nothing modified." << endl;
        }
    }
}

double ShoppingCart::getTotalCost()
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size(); i++)
    {
        sum += cartItems[i].getQuantity() * cartItems[i].getPrice();   
    }
    return sum;
}

void ShoppingCart::printCart()
{
    cout << customerName << "'s Shopping Cart" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.size(); i++)
    {
        cartItems.at(i).printItemCost();
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Total: $" << getTotalCost() << endl;
}
```

***ShoppingCart.h***

```
#ifndef ShoppingCart_hpp
#define ShoppingCart_hpp


#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "ItemToPurchase.h"
using namespace std;

class ShoppingCart
{
    private:
       string customerName;
       vector<ItemToPurchase> cartItems;

    public:
       ShoppingCart();
       ShoppingCart(string name);
       string getCustomerName() const;
       void addItem(ItemToPurchase);
       void removeItem(string);
       void changeQuantity(string, int);
       double getTotalCost();
       void printCart();
};

#endif
```

Comment: As a side note, it is usually not a good practice to use the `using namespace std` within a header file (i.e.- in the case of, for instance, your `customerName` class member: std::string customerName)

Comment: I personally believe that it's not a good idea and I don't like using it but my professor make us do that.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this code. Perhaps forgetting to add an item? Setting a quantity or price to zero? Maybe you could add a check for that in `changeQuantity`, etc.

Comment: I can see four possible reasons: 1) the cart is empty; 2) your items have a zero quantity; 3) your items have a zero price; 4) some items have a negative price or quantity and they add up to zero. I suspect that you either a) add items to a different cart from the one you're inspecting, or b) add default-constructed items to the cart.

Comment: As said above (ish), although you have the ability to add an item, theres no where that I can see where you set a prices for the item. Therefore everything is zero.

Comment: How does that even compile, with no `main()`?

Comment: Here is my Main:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is, that getTotalCost adds 0 values:

```
cartItems[i].getQuantity() * cartItems[i].getPrice();
```

If one of the two factors is zero, the whole sum stays 0.